# WiX Project VS 2015 Directories are not created

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2015, wix, windows-installer, registry

I followed a simple YouTube instruction video on how to do a very basic WiX Setup to create an msi file. 
The purpose is to place certain files into certain directories and make 4 registry entries. I did this with the Setup Project built into VS 2015 with great result. The WiX Project however does not work. This is my first time working with XML too.

For example, here I defined the directories:

```
<Fragment>
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="Programfiles">
    <Directory Id="MSOFFICEFOLDER" Name="Microsoft Office">
      <Directory Id="OFFICE14FOLDER" Name="Office14" />
        <Directory Id="LIBRARY" Name="Library">
        <Directory Id="MAKRO" Name="Makro">                
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
        </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

Here I put the files into the folders:

```
<!-- Adding files to Office14 folders -->
<Fragment>
  <DirectoryRef Id="OFFICE14FOLDER">
    <Component Id="umrch.hlp" Guid="*">
      <File Id="umrch.hlp" Source="MySourceFiles\UMRCH.HLP" KeyPath="yes" 
Checksum="yes"/>
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>

  <DirectoryRef Id="LIBRARY">
    <Component Id="umrch.xla" Guid="*">
      <File Id="umrch.xla" Source="MySourceFiles\umrch.xla" KeyPath="yes" 
Checksum="yes"/>
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>

  <DirectoryRef Id="MAKRO">
    <Component Id="umrch.xla" Guid="*">
      <File Id="umrch.xla" Source="MySourceFiles\umrch.xla" KeyPath="yes" 
Checksum="yes"/>
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>


  <!-- Adding files to Company folders-->
  <DirectoryRef Id="DATA">
    <Component Id="DATAfiles" Guid="*">
      <File Id="defumrch.dat" Source="MySourceFiles\defumrch.dat" 
KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
      <File Id="LL_UMRCH.DAT" Source="MySourceFiles\LL_UMRCH.DAT" 
KeyPath="no" Checksum="yes"/>
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>

  <DirectoryRef Id="VERSION">
    <Component Id="VERSIONfiles" Guid="*">
      <File Id="umrch_Readme.doc" Source="MySourceFiles\umrch_Readme.doc" 
KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
       <File Id="umrch_Version.txt" Source="MySourceFiles\umrch_Version.txt" 
KeyPath="no" Checksum="yes"/>
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>


  <!-- Adding files to Windows folder-->
  <DirectoryRef Id="WindowsFolder">
    <Component Id="WINDOWSfiles" Guid="">
     <File Id="umrch.dll" Source="MySourceFiles\umrch.dll" KeyPath="yes" 
Checksum="yes"/>
      <File Id="umrch.lib" Source="MySourceFiles\umrch.lib" KeyPath="no" 
Checksum="yes"/>
      <File Id="umrch.mif" Source="MySourceFiles\umrch.mif" KeyPath="no" 
Checksum="yes"/>
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
```

And here they should be installed:

```
    <Fragment>
  <!-- Tell WiX to install the files -->
  <Feature Id="xlahelp" Title="XLA and help files" Level="1">
    <ComponentRef Id="umrch.hlp" />
    <ComponentRef Id="umrch.xla" />
  </Feature>

  <Feature Id="COMPANYfiles" Title="Company files" Level="1">
    <ComponentRef Id="DATAfiles" />
    <ComponentRef Id="VERSIONfiles" />
  </Feature>

  <Feature Id="WindowsFiles" Title="Windows files" Level="1">
    <ComponentRef Id="WINDOWSfiles" />
  </Feature>

  <Feature Id="Registry" Title="umrch" Level="1">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="Registry"/>
  </Feature>
</Fragment>
```

Are there some references missing or did I wrongly use XML?

Edit: Here is the Product wix

```
<Product Id="*" Name="UMRCH" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Sample" UpgradeCode="ee45fb60-6741-4424-8136-dfc0d679629a">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />


</Product>
```

Edit for Stein Åsmul:

DATA and VERSION should be defined here:

```
  <Fragment>
<Directory Id="WindowsVolume" Name="WindowsVolume">
   <Directory Id="!(bind.property.Manufacturer)" Name="!(bind.property.Manufacturer)">
     <Directory Id="UMRCH" Name="!(bind.property.ProductName)" />
      <Directory Id="DATA" Name="data">
      <Directory Id="VERSION" Name="version" />   
       </Directory>
     </Directory>
   </Directory>
```

It also does compile when using WiX. The .msi file is built without any errors occuring. 
When opening it with SuperOrca, it shows a tab _Validation, since I am very new to this I have no idea on how to read the .msi within Orca though.

I now also added a gist to github for better visibility.

[Product/Registry](https://gist.github.com/coltfinger/5eda0768fcfd07239fc244089d436226)

Comment: Can you supply the wxs that defines your `<Product>` as well? If you don't properly reference these fragments you made (eventually being referenced in the `<Product>`), everything will be discarded at compile time.

Comment: I updated my my original post!

Comment: It would be better to just show your entire WiX source so it can be simply copied and pasted for others to reproduce.

Comment: I think I sort of did, the link at the end provides the two .wxs files which is all I have in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Does this file compile at all when using WiX?** It looks like you have not defined some of the directories you install to. For example DATA and VERSION. If you get an output MSI file, what does it look like when you open it with Orca? Have you run validation on your MSI?

I will "evolve" this answer once you have updated your question with some more detail. Let's try to minimize the use of comments for "discussion".